# Euler sequence and Cotangent bundle on $\mathbb P^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\Omega^1_{\mathbb P^2}$ be the cotangent bundle over $\mathbb P^2$. Is it necessarily true that $h^1(\Omega^1_{\mathbb P^2}(2)) \neq 0$?

From Euler exact sequence, we have $h^1(\Omega^1_{\mathbb P^2}(2)) =h^0(\Omega^1_{\mathbb P^2}(2))-3$.

Can we say $h^0(\Omega^1_{\mathbb P^2}(2)) \geq 4$? (Is this because $h^0(\Omega^1_{\mathbb P^2}(2)) \geq h^0(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(2))$?

Comment: How do you use Euler sequence?

Comment: @Sasha, Consider $0 \to \Omega^1_{\mathbb P^2} \to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(-1)^3 \to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2} \to 0$, then tensor it with $\mathcal O(2)$ and take cohomology  and noting that $h^1(\mathcal O(1))=0$, I obtained the relation.

Comment: You probably know the map $\mathcal{O}(-1)^3 \to \mathcal{O}$. Using it, you can compute the map on $H^0$ after the twist, and thus compute the cohomology of $\Omega(2)$.

Comment: Alternatively, you can extend this map to a Koszul complex, and thus obtain another resolution $$0 \to \mathcal{O}(-3) \to \mathcal{O}(-2)^3 \to \Omega \to 0.$$ The computation of cohomology with this sequence is much easier.

Comment: @Sasha, But this Koszul complex exact sequence gives us $h^1(\Omega^1_{\mathbb P^2}(2)) = 0$, Can we say instead $h^1(\Omega^1_{\mathbb P^2}(2+t))  \neq 0$, for some appropriate $t$?

Comment: You can use the resolutions to answer this question.

Comment: @Sasha, thanks. Infact in this case $h^1(\Omega^1_{\mathbb P^2}) =1$